# KDE Spectacle includeMousePointer on rectangular

Tags: kde-plasma

The KDE Daemon global shortcuts allow to choose a shortcut for `Take Rectangular Region Screenshot`, it defaults to `Meta+Shift+PrtScr`.

However that takes a screenshot **with** the mouse pointer, how do I disable that?

When I open Spectacle, the *includeMousePointer* is not checked, so apparently that's a different setting.

Apparently this [commit](https://github.com/KDE/spectacle/commit/e6f41e4e712065aee6416da79f4d538f74116a58) seems to say it's possible to do so but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press the hotkey, a D-Bus command is invoked. These commands accept arguments instead of looking at configuration files for maximum flexibility.

The actual D-Bus command that you would need to invoke is:

```
qdbus org.kde.Spectacle / org.kde.Spectacle.RectangularRegion false
```

The argument for this `RectangularRegion` method indicates the value for `includeMousePointer`. The commit you referenced indeed makes the default hotkey action call this with a `true` argument instead of `false`.

---

If you want to change the default, edit `spectacle.khotkeys` file in your system. Locate the `[Data_1_4Actions0]` section, and change `Arguments=true` to `Arguments=false`. The result should look like this:

```
[Data_1_4Actions0]
Arguments=false
Call=RectangularRegion
RemoteApp=org.kde.Spectacle
RemoteObj=/
Type=DBUS
```

It might be required to restart your session after changing this.

Comment: /usr/share/khotkeys/spectacle.khotkeys is indeed the the file I was looking for!

Comment: Changing it didn't do the trick. However, I noticed there is a "Custom Shortcut" menu that has a "Screenshot" menu that has a "Tab" that has "Arguments" that contains "true" and coule be changed to "false"! Could you edit your answer?

I don't know why changing the .khotkeys didn't change the behavior, maybe because it's overriden?

Comment: @RobertVandenEynde, could you check if you have a `spectacle.khotkeys` file anywhere under `~/.local` ?

Comment: Nope, `cd ~/.local; find . | grep khotkeys` gives nothing.